# Why does Active Directory: Domain Services configuration sit at "Examining DNS configuration"?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I have uninstalled, rebooted, reinstalled, added, removed, changed, reconfigured everything imaginable related to AD: DS and it refuses to configure via dcpromo.exe.

It sits at "Examining DNS configuration" for over an hour.
It adds things to the dcpromoui.log such as:

`dcpromoui F04.CB4 0245 19:10:32.078   Dns_CountParentNsRecordsForDomain NS Enumeration for mysite.comon parent . failed, returned 1722`

`dcpromoui F04.CB4 0246 19:10:32.078   Dns_CountParentNsRecordsForDomain performing NS Enumeration for mysite.comon parent .`

I'm adding the role for AD: DS with the integrated DNS; I don't have a separate DNS role.

Any suggestions other than reconfiguration by hammer would be great.

Comment: Is this the first DC you're trying to add to a new forest, or an additional DC that you're promoting?

Comment: I'm playing with AD for the first time. So I guess I'm taking my domain and adding that to a new forest. Previously I configured it as corporate.mysite.com from a tutorial. I wanted to redo this as mysite.com instead this time, so I could have myserver.mysite.com instead of myserver.corporate.mysite.com or something crazy as the default. I could also quite possibly have no clue how to set this up correctly.

Comment: It seems to work just fine when I do "corporate.mysite.com". This is apparently the normal practice though. No clue as to why.

Comment: Don't use ever a top-level domain name for your AD name unless you will never ever use that same name for an external website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this I made AD responsible for corporate.mysite.com. I delegated authority for corporate.mysite.com from mysite.com's DNS to the corporate.mysite.com DNS.

When using mysite.com as the domain for AD, it simply hung indefinitely. Why? I don't really know. But I just know that any subdomain for mysite.com worked fine.

If someone has a deep explanation of why this is the case, I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: We're you literally using mysite.com?

Comment: I am confused. Are you asking a question or making a statement? It would be odd to ask "We are you literally using mysite.com?" Anyway, if you mean to ask if I'm actually using mysite.com, then no.

Comment: I did mean to say "were" instead of "we're". My iPad autocorrected it and I didn't catch the error. If that obvious typo confuses you, then I'd take a step back from Active Directory for a while :)

Comment: I love auto correction. But anyway, AD seems like a great thing to step away from even when understanding your typo. I'm getting pretty deep into why people get mad at it, but also why others love it. Good times. :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I'd add what I've observed from a slow "Examining DNS configuration" during dcpromo here, on Windows Server 2008 R2.

The new Domain Controller repeatedly tried to contact each of the Internet's root-servers on TCP/135, the RPC Endpoint Mapper.  Later, the wizard warned that it would not be able to set up a DNS Delegation for my domain because the parent DNS server is not running Windows or is not dynamic.

So it seems it is trying to set up a DNS Delegation from the parent domain (as in ".com") for your/my company (mysite.com) to direct DNS queries to your local Domain Controller (also the wizard is assuming you'll want this new DC to also be a DNS server).

Perhaps, depending on what you're doing to your outbound traffic to the root DNS servers (rejecting, blackholing, etc.) it may take shorter or longer to timeout?

Comment: In my case, I'm using a fake top-level domain.  The domain is something like "mycompany.internal".  So my server is repeatedly trying to find the non-existant ".internal" domain from the Internet root servers.